# Set an on click listener on button in a fragment in the main activity file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have tried to do some research on the topic and I am attempting to add an on-click listener for a button in a fragment in the main activity. So when I click a button in a fragment the click can get registered in the main activity file.

Comment: Callback using context. But would be useful to know what you're trying to do and see if there's a better solution

Comment: You should have a reference to the fragment in that container activity; because it did the transaction in it; using it, you can setup a custom listener between the activity & fragment

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. Are you trying to say that I should create a listener and override it in the main activity?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom broadcast receiver
You will register a receiver on button click in fragment
Then in activity apply action if this broadcast action equal to this custom action

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. Could you explain in code?

Answer (score 0):

you can use interface for this problem

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. Could you explain in code?